# Order by number of times a tuple appears- msql

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

Example of table

```
Name FriendName
A     C,
A     D,
B     Z,
E     B,
E     F,
E     G,
```

I want to display the table such as that the name with the most friends should show first with all its respective tuples. Like the output I want is:

```
E     B,
E     F,
E     G,
A     C,
A     D,
B     Z,
```

When I use Group By name Order By Count(*) it only shows one tuple wrt name and not all the tuples 
like `E B, A C, B Z`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood, and to have helped.

```
SELECT B.Name,B.FriendName FROM
(

SELECT 
A.Name,COUNT(A.Name) AS COUNTER
FROM TABLE A
GROUP BY A.Name

) TB 
INNER JOIN TABLE B
ON TB.Name = B.Name
ORDER BY COUNTER DESC
```